# How to get the active view in an iOS application from the app delegate?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiview

how can i get the currently active view (the main view currently being viewed by the user) from the app delegate for references sake?

Comment: Define "main view". There could be several `UIView` objects (and subclasses) on-screen at once. Which one would you expect to get?

Comment: Say the user is currently on a screen to perform a specific action, I want to get the viewcontroller for the container view for that screen

Comment: You'll have to keep track of that yourself. Like views, there could be more than one view controller active on the screen.

Answer (score 34):

```
UIWindow *window = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];
UIView *topView = window.rootViewController.view;
```

Answer (score 17):

All top answers **doesn't work with modal presented views!**
Use this code instead:

`UIView * topView = [[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] subviews] lastObject];`

Answer (score 9):

It depends on how your app is set up.

Typically, your app delegate will have a main view controller property that will let you get to it.

To get your app delegate

```
MyAppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

UIView *topView = appDelegate.viewController.view;
```

If your app has a navigation controller property in the app delegate you can do something like this.

```
UIView *topView = appDelegate.navigationController.topViewController.view;
```

Comment: The third line gives me an error: Property 'navigationController' not found on object of type 'kzAppDelegate'

Comment: you probably aren't using a navigation controller then. Look at the second line of code in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I found this and it works great for me for all types of segues and view controllers.

```
+(UIViewController*) getTopController{
    UIViewController *topViewController = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController;

    while (topViewController.presentedViewController) {
        topViewController = topViewController.presentedViewController;
    }

    return topViewController;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `[appDelegate.navigationController.topViewController class]` to log the class of the controller or get the title property to know which one it is.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps you

```
UINavigationController *navCnt = (UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController;

if([navCnt.topViewController isMemberOfClass:[WebViewController class]])
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}
else
return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
```

Answer (score 0):

Anywhere in the app you can get your rootViewController View also like that:

```
id<UIApplicationDelegate> appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
UIView *rootView = appDelegate.window.rootViewController.view;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [Eric's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12684721/2684720):

```
+ (UIViewController*) topMostController
{
    UIViewController *topController = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController;

    while (topController.presentedViewController) {
        topController = topController.presentedViewController;
    }

    return topController;
}
```