# How to get current viewController class name?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

but the problem is that my app has both UInavigationController and UITabBarController

so calling navigaionController.topViewController tells me that i have UItabBarController
and

self.window.rootViewController returns UINavigationController

thank's a lot

Comment: You may even have multiple Navigation Controllers. One for each tab is possible. However, I do not really understand your question and your problem. Could you please try rephrasing your question?

Comment: If you have pushed UITabBarController to UINavigationController stack, you shouldn't do that.

Comment: [link](http://postimage.org/image/3t7hwesct/) ok here is screenshot maybe it make my quesion clear. Sorry for another site - i've not enough points  to post images.

Comment: The real question is what do you need it for? The majority of the time you shouldn't care that much what the name of a class is at runtime, maybe you are trying to solve a problem in the wrong way...

Comment: trying to set question in another way: i have a MyViewController class, so i create an instance of it, then i add UInavigationController on it, and then i add UITabBarController on it. And the problem is how to get the name "MyViewController"

Comment: To Paul.s. Ok. All of my ViewControllers have two diffrent superclasses with a different method which i need to call from my app delegate. So i need to know who's the superclass of the current view controller - and i can call the right method

Comment: Well seems as you are going to have a chunk of if statements why not just be slightly more object oriented and ask the class if it responds to each of the methods? `[viewController respondsToSelector:@selector(myMethod)];`. Also use @ followed by a name or Stack overflow does not notify the person you are talking to that you have replied

Comment: @paul.s isn't respondsToSelector deprecated/discouraged? I'm on my phone so it's hard to check but I feel like I heard something about that.

Comment: @Dustin i would doubt that very much. It's pretty essential for allowing flexibility - how do you think `@optional` protocol methods work? They first check if the object implements the method before calling it... I think using it can be a bit of a code smell (like the situation above) and make you think of a redesign

Comment: Okay, I looked it up and it's normally considered fine. However, in a case like this where it's used to dynamically check for a class type it's discouraged (so is isKindOfClass) @Paul.s

Comment: @Dustin but the OP really wants to know what method they can run e.g. if the class will respond to a selector - I think knowing the class was just the OP's original idea on how to solve the problem.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6131205/iphone-how-to-find-topmost-view-controller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check for the kind of class it is using
[VC isKindOfClass:(myVCClass class)]

Answer (score 0):

The tabbarcontroller is designed to be the top/root viewcontroller of your application. From the documentation:

> Because the UITabBarController class inherits from the UIViewController class, tab bar controllers have their own view that is accessible through the view property. When deploying a tab bar interface, you must install this view as the root of your window. Unlike other view controllers, a tab bar interface should never be installed as a child of another view controller.

Have the navigationcontroller inside the tabs and have the other view controllers inside the navigationcontrollers on the tabs.

Answer (score 0):

view.class returns a class name as a string:

```
NSLog (@"Class:%@", view.class);
```