# Changing UIViewController from AppDelegate on ios for push notification

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

When a user gets a push notification, I want the app to open up to a certain UIViewController. I'm in xCode 5 with storyboard.

I think my code is close but it is throwing an error

Here is the method in AppDelegate

```
    - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
{
    UINavigationController *nav = (UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController;
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main_iPhone" bundle:nil];
    RewardList *vc = (RewardList *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"RewardList"];
    [nav pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
}
```

It errors out on the `[nav pushViewController:vc animated:YES];`  I'm not quite sure what is going on. Can someone help shed light on this issue?

Here is the error:

`-[SplashViewController pushViewController:animated:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1f862630 2013-12-12 17:58:28.719 appName[473:907] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[SplashViewController pushViewController:animated:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1f862630'`

EDIT:
The app root view controller is SplashNavigationController which is a UIViewController. From there I have a UITabBarController. Inside of that on my 3rd tab, is RewardList which is also a UIViewController.  I need to go from whatever the current view is, to my 3rd tab, the RewardList tab.

I'm finding a lot of posts on this, but nothing seems to work in my case.

Comment: are you sure nav is a UINavigationController?

Comment: It's hard to answer your question without knowing what the view controller hierarchy is in the storyboard. It's clear from the error, that the window's root view controller is a SplashViewController, not a UINavigationController. So, what is your hierarchy?

Comment: Thanks for all the responses. I'm not clear on how the hierarchy works. Been trying to find a tutorial on this to better understand it. I did an EDIT on my post to give more information on the hierarchy. Let me know if more information is needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing I would do to fix this is change the structure so the tab bar controller is the root view controller of the window. If you want your splash screen to come up first, then present that modally (with no animation) from the viewDidAppear method in the controller in the first tab. When you're done with that screen, you can just dismiss it, and you'll be in the first controller. If you make that change, then doing what you want in the app delegate will be simple,

```
  - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {
         UITabBarController *tbc = (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;
         tbc.selectedIndex = 2;
  }
```

I would also suggest that you study Apple's "View Controller Programming Guide for iOS" to learn about view controllers and their life cycle.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your root view controller is a view controller of the class SplashViewController. Is SplashViewController a subclass of UINavigationController? It has to be, or you'll get that error.

Comment: Ah, it is not. It is a subclass of UIViewController. RewardList is also a subclass of UIViewController but it has a Navigation Controller. So I'm guessing that nav is my SplashViewController because I have the storyboard defaulting to that. I'm still not clear on how to change from the current UIViewController to the RewardList UIViewController

Answer (score 0):

There are some ways to get top most view controller on this thread.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/23603265/

I like this code because it's very simple.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/23603265/1971596

```
- (UIViewController*)topViewController {
    return [self topViewControllerWithRootViewController:[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController];
}

- (UIViewController*)topViewControllerWithRootViewController:(UIViewController*)rootViewController {
    if ([rootViewController isKindOfClass:[UITabBarController class]]) {
        UITabBarController* tabBarController = (UITabBarController*)rootViewController;
        return [self topViewControllerWithRootViewController:tabBarController.selectedViewController];
    } else if ([rootViewController isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]]) {
        UINavigationController* navigationController = (UINavigationController*)rootViewController;
        return [self topViewControllerWithRootViewController:navigationController.visibleViewController];
    } else if (rootViewController.presentedViewController) {
        UIViewController* presentedViewController = rootViewController.presentedViewController;
        return [self topViewControllerWithRootViewController:presentedViewController];
    } else {
        return rootViewController;
    }
}
```

And then you just present view controller from top most view controller.