# Get the root ViewController - Objective-C

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, storyboard, root

Here's my problem: I've actually created a `custom segue` to manage in a different way the transitions between my `UIViewControllers` (I'm working on a `Storyboard` based project). I added some animations using `CATransform3D` to move the views...so...when I do that, the only thing I can see in the background is a black view.

I would love to know how to change that color and if is possible to replace it with a `UIImageView`. Do you have any trick/idea to do that?

Thanks! :)

[image]

Comment: Can you post your view setup? (A screenshot of the storyboard or so). Anyway you can try to access `self.window.rootViewController` and add a subview there.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6131321/581994

Comment: @SebastianWramba I tried this even though it's not working :( --> SecondViewController *secV = [[SecondViewController alloc] init];
    secV.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController addChildViewController:secV];

Comment: @SebastianWramba Just added a screenshot

Answer (score 0):

You can try following if you are sure the black view is a root controller's view:

```
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"my_image"]];
UIView *rootView = [[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController.view];
[rootView insertSubview:imageView atIndex:0];
```

Comment: Just tried your code...but it still shows the black screen in the background...does it mean that what I see is not the rootView? If so...how can I access it?

Comment: Have you tried to change rootView bg color? Window bg color? It will be great to clarify your views stack. Try to change bg color of your navigation controller please

Answer (score 0):

Actually，this is a grave, but I would leave the answer for later-comers.

We know that iOS is migrated from OS X, so all viewControllers are in `UIWindow`, `the black color` is the `backgroundColor of the window`. so that you `should not` find any `root viewController`, what you find is `the top window`.

if you want to `change the black backgroundColor to other color`, like white, do:

```
  UIWindow *window = [[UIApplication sharedApplication].windows lastObject];
  window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```