# show alertController from a custom class

Tags: ios, swift, alert, nsobject, uialertcontroller

I'm trying to show an AlertController from a class that I've made.
Since AlertController is a subclass of UIResponder I'm using the following line of code that Xcode is suggesting me

```
superclass?.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

But I cannot compile because AnyClass? does not have any member presentViewController.
My class is a subclass of NSObject.

Any other solution?
Thanks

Comment: `presentViewController` is a method of `UIViewController`, not of `NSObject`

Comment: @Krumelur I know, but I'm trying to show an UIAlertController from my class. Is there any other workaround?

Answer (score 7):

Well you just need to find the topmost view controller and present the `alertcontroller` from there.

```
UIViewController *topController = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController;

while (topController.presentedViewController) {
    topController = topController.presentedViewController;
}
[topController presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

[credits](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12684721/2099097)

**Note:** This is objective-c version of the code. Kindly convert it to swift accordingly.

**SWIFT**

```
let topController = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow!.rootViewController as UIViewController

while (topController.presentedViewController) {
    topController = topController.presentedViewController;
}
topController.presentViewController(alertController, animated:true, completion:nil)
```

Comment: Sorry but I asked for swift and I don't know what to do with Obj C. Please consider to revise using swift language

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your understanding of "from". An alert appears in front of some view in the interface. Thus, we need to know *what* view. The answer is: the main view of some view controller - a view controller whose main view is in the interface.

Thus, only a view controller whose main view is in the interface can be told to present an alert. It is that view controller that you must present "from".

You'll need to have some way of getting a reference to that view controller from wherever your code is, so that your code can tell that view controller to present the alert. That in itself can be an interesting problem; indeed, "getting a reference" to an existing object is a major part of the art of Cocoa programming.

Comment: It's such an important problem ("getting a reference") that I devote a section of my book to it: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch13.html#_instance_visibility It might give you some ideas.

Comment: Genius! Just include the UIViewController in the init method and voila. Done.

Answer (score 1):

From ur view Controller u have pass Controller's reference ,message ,title such as

```
Settings.getAlertViewConroller(self, DialogTitle: "Test Sale", strDialogMessege: "You are performing a test sale. This is not a real transaction.")
```

where Setting is the subclass of NSObject.In Setting class u have to define method as

```
class func getAlertViewConroller(globleAlert:UIViewController,DialogTitle:NSString,strDialogMessege:NSString){


    let actionSheetController: UIAlertController = UIAlertController(title: DialogTitle, message: strDialogMessege, preferredStyle: .Alert)


    let nextAction: UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default) { action -> Void in

    }
    actionSheetController.addAction(nextAction)

    globleAlert.presentViewController(actionSheetController, animated: true, completion:nil)

}
```

i.e presenting UIAlertController.

Answer (score 1):

Latest Swift:

```
    var topController:UIViewController = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow!.rootViewController!
    while ((topController.presentedViewController) != nil) {
        topController = topController.presentedViewController!;
    }
    topController.present(alertController, animated:true, completion:nil)
```