# Calling presentViewController from custom class

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller

I read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29323449/how-to-call-presentviewcontroller-from-inside-class) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27735050/show-alertcontroller-from-a-custom-class) on how to call a presentViewController form outside a UIViewController subclass. In my case, the custom class is a subclass of NSObject. The following approach is the only one that works (from the examples I read):

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.rootViewController?.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

My question: is there a better solution that does not rely on the appDelegate (as I understood this approach is design-wise not very neat)...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I sometimes create a utilities class to display alerts and such. What I usually do is have my methods for presenting view controllers take the current view controller as a parameter. That approach works pretty well.

### EDIT:

Here is an example method from a file Utils.swift in one of my projects. It defines a class function that displays a UIAlertController alert on the current view controller:

```
class Utils
{
  static let sharedUtils = Utils()
  
  class func showAlertOnVC(
    targetVC: UIViewController, 
    var title: String, 
    var message: String)
  {
    title = NSLocalizedString(title, comment: "")
    message = NSLocalizedString(message, comment: "")
    let alert = UIAlertController(
      title: title, 
      message: message, 
      preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
    let okButton = UIAlertAction(
      title:"OK",
      style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default,
      handler:
      {
        (alert: UIAlertAction!)  in
    })
    alert.addAction(okButton)
    targetVC.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
  }
}
```

The code above defines a class Utils. Note that it does not have any base class, which is Ok in Swift.

Next it defines a public static variable sharedUtils that you can use to get access to the singleton Utils class.

Finally, it defines a class method `showAlertOnVC` that can be used to display a UIAlertController alert on top of the current view controller. To use `showAlertOnVC` you call it from the current view controller and pass self as the `targetVC` parameter.

Comment: And what class does that utilities class subclass?

Comment: Doesn't matter. In Objective-C, NSObject. In Swift, no base class.

Comment: But that is comparable to my current solution, which also has no base class. My question is how to avoid calling the AppDelegate, which I guess will still be necessary if this class does not subclass a ViewController...

Comment: No. Create a utilities class. Put your methods in that. You can make the methods class methods if they need instance variables, or you can make the utilities class a singleton. Classes in Swift don't have to subclass anything, unlike Objective-C.

Comment: This seems to work! For clarity, you may consider formatting your code as code. Nevertheless, I accepted your answer... thanks!

Comment: Yup. I tend to type code not indented, and then indent it before posting. In this case I forgot to indent the code before posting.

Comment: In my comment above I should have said "you can make the methods class methods if they **don't** need instance variables, or you can make the utilities class a singleton."

Answer (score 3):

This in my opinion is the easiest solution:

```
class Utils {
  static  func displayTheAlert(targetVC: UIViewController, title: String, message: String){
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
        alert.addAction((UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: {(action) -> Void in
        })))
        targetVC.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

// then to call it

```
Utils.displayTheAlert(self, title: "Fout", message: "Uw bestelling is nog niet klaar")
```

Answer (score 2):

From the design point of View, it is not advisable for the model class(NSObject) to interact directly with View. It does not conform to the MVC Pattern . Avoid using UIKIT in the NSObject class.