# How to create separate orientation for specific view controller using objective C?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to `programmatically create UI orientation (portrait and landscape)` using Objective C for all devices. Here the problem is I have multiple `view controllers`. I want to use `multiple orientation` into particular view controller.

```
For Ex: 

Splash screen (App delegate - Portrait)
Login screen (Portrait)
Home screen (Both)
```

If I controlled by below method into `App delegate root class` then I cant enable both `orientation` into `home view controller`. Its showing black screen.

```
- (NSUInteger) application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window {

    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try by following implementation. What here doing is, we sends the interfaceorientation we need for the visible view controller from app delegate. For that fist finds the visible viewcontroler and gets its supported interface orientation, If supportedInterfaceOrientations method not implemented in the visible view controller, return default orientation.

```
- (UIInterfaceOrientationMask)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window  {
    UIViewController *topController = [self topmostViewController];

    if ([topController respondsToSelector:@selector(supportedInterfaceOrientations)]) {
        return [topController supportedInterfaceOrientations];
    }

    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown;
}

- (UIViewController *)topmostViewController {
    UIViewController *topController = self.window.rootViewController;

    return [self topViewControllerWithRootViewController:topController];
}

- (UIViewController *)topViewControllerWithRootViewController:(UIViewController *)rootViewController {

    if ([rootViewController isKindOfClass:[UITabBarController class]]) {
        UITabBarController* tabBarController = (UITabBarController*)rootViewController;
        return [self topViewControllerWithRootViewController:tabBarController.selectedViewController];
    } else if ([rootViewController isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]]) {
        UINavigationController* navigationController = (UINavigationController*)rootViewController;
        return [self topViewControllerWithRootViewController:navigationController.topViewController];// dont use visible view controller, since it will return the presented ViewController, it may be UIAlertController.
    } else if (rootViewController.presentedViewController && ![rootViewController.presentedViewController isKindOfClass:[UIAlertController class]]) {
        UIViewController* presentedViewController = rootViewController.presentedViewController;
        return [self topViewControllerWithRootViewController:presentedViewController];
    } else {
        return rootViewController;
    }
}
```

And if you want to display any view controller with orientation other than `UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown` implement following method in your view controller

```
- (UIInterfaceOrientationMask)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return <whichever orientation you need>;
}
```

**UPDATE:**

Make sure that you selected only the orientations you needed for initial view controller in target settings.

Ref: Finding topmost view controller code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6131205/iphone-how-to-find-topmost-view-controller#17578272) with slight modification by addressing UIAlertcontroller presented case

Comment: have you implemented -supportedInterfaceOrientations in your view controllers

Comment: in the appdelegate itself

Comment: Conflicting return type in implementation of 'application:supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:': 'NSUInteger' (aka 'unsigned int') vs 'UIInterfaceOrientationMask' (aka 'enum UIInterfaceOrientationMask')

Comment: btw in the target settings which orientaions are selected?

Comment: I think you are using xcode 6.x. once you update to 7 rhe warning will go away

Comment: try checking only portrait in target settings

Comment: Awesome buddy...Its working cool! Thank you! Can we deleted unwanted commends. Plz

Comment: no let it be there. so others can understand if they met same issues. and I will update the answer also. if your problem solved pls accept it. so any other user can understand this is working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90194/discussion-between-johnykutty-and-apple-ajay).