# How do you show a screen from anywhere in your iOS app?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

**Situation**

An iOS app built in Xamarin with 4 screens. When you start the app it attempts to retrieve information to populate the first screen. If user token expired an exception is thrown. The **AppDelegate** listens for these messages and when received will show the login screen:

`_window.RootViewController.PresentViewController(_loginViewController, true, null);`

(`_window` is the first screen. `_loginViewController` is the screen the user enters their username and password.)

This works OK when on the first screen. But I need a way to show `_loginViewController` from ANY screen.

**Problem/Questions**

- From AppDelegate, is there a way to know what screen is the current screen?
- Is there a different way I should be structuring my project to be able to show the login screen no matter where I am in the app?
- Are there common practices for this scenario?

*Note: My project is in Xamarin and supports iOS 8+ but I'm sure if I got a Swift solution I could work with that as well.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a method in the AppDelegate like so:

```
public void ShowLoginView()
{
    _window.RootViewController.PresentViewController(_loginViewController,true,null);
}
```

Then Call it from any ViewController like so:

```
var appDelegate = (AppDelegate)UIApplication.SharedApplication.Delegate;
appDelegate.ShowLoginView ();
```

And Dismiss it in the LoginViewController with this:

```
DismissModalViewController (true);
```

This will allow you to keep your navigation stack if you are using one.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code to show login screen from AppDelegate regardless of the current window:

```
var loginViewController = UIStoryboard.FromName("MainStoryboard", NSBundle.MainBundle).InstantiateViewController("LoginPageViewController") as LoginPageViewController;
Window.RootViewController = loginViewController;
```

Comment: Not a bad idea, I would add that you could keep a handle on the original RootViewController, so you could restore the previous hierarchy once the user has logged in.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the top-most view controller through the following code defined as a static property on your `AppDelegate`:

```
[Register("AppDelegate")]
public partial class AppDelegate : UIApplicationDelegate
{

    public static UIViewController TopViewController
    {
        get
        {
            return TopViewControllerWithRootViewController(UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.RootViewController);
        }
    }

    public static UIViewController TopViewControllerWithRootViewController(UIViewController rootViewController)
    {
        if (rootViewController is UITabBarController)
        {
            var tabBarController = rootViewController as UITabBarController;
            return TopViewControllerWithRootViewController(tabBarController.SelectedViewController);

        }
        if (rootViewController is UINavigationController)
        {
            var navBarController = rootViewController as UINavigationController;
            return TopViewControllerWithRootViewController(navBarController.VisibleViewController);
        }

        var presentedViewController = rootViewController.PresentedViewController;

        if (presentedViewController != null)
        {
            return TopViewControllerWithRootViewController(presentedViewController);
        }

        return rootViewController;
```

This is a C# port of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17578272/1099111).

To present a view controller from anywhere in you app, use the above code like so:

```
MFMailComposeViewController mailController = new MFMailComposeViewController();

// ...

AppDelegate.TopViewController.PresentViewController(mailController, true, null);
```