# How to present modally UIViewController in applicationWillEnterForeground method in app delegate iOS10 Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, foreground, presentviewcontroller

I wanna present a UIViewController when come into foreground app.
And i am using this code in **applicationWillEnterForeground** method in Objective C appDelegate app , but it does not works for me.

```
UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
PasscodeViewController *vc = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"passcodeVCID"];
[self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: What do you reckon is `self` inside appDelegate?

Comment: i used to using SELF in uiviewcontroller. there is works. but i dont know how to handle it here.

Comment: That's because in UIViewController class, self is a ViewController. `presentViewController` is a method defined in UIViewController.h so it works there. In AppDelegate, self is AppDelegate and it has no method called `presentViewController`.

Comment: You need to access your currently visible VC first and then use that instance to call the presentViewController method. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39416067/4029561) to learn how can you get current visible VC.

Answer (score 0):

```
UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
PasscodeViewController *vc = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"passcodeVCID"];

// Need to present with rootviewcontroller

[self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: i used this code into applicationWillEnterForeground method but it does not work.

Comment: try once with

[self.window.rootViewController.navigationController presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];