# Get visibleViewController using UIWindow?

Tags: ios, swift

So, I have `self` as `UIWindow`, but how can I get visibleViewController at current moment?

Comment: have you use UINavigationController?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IN swift3:

```
func getVisibleViewController(_ rootViewController: UIViewController?) -> UIViewController? {

    var rootVC = rootViewController
    if rootVC == nil {
        rootVC = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController
    }

    if rootVC?.presentedViewController == nil {
        return rootVC
    }

    if let presented = rootVC?.presentedViewController {
        if presented.isKind(of: UINavigationController.self) {
            let navigationController = presented as! UINavigationController
            return navigationController.viewControllers.last!
        }

        if presented.isKind(of: UITabBarController.self) {
            let tabBarController = presented as! UITabBarController
            return tabBarController.selectedViewController!
        }

        return getVisibleViewController(presented)
    }
    return nil
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you add the child view controller:

```
let viewControllersVisible = self.rootViewController?.childViewControllers.filter({ $0.isVisible && $0.view.window })
```

This returns an array of `UIViewControllers` added in your view hierarchy, it doesn't say if the user is actually able to see those view controllers, depends on your hierarchy.

if you present modally just a view controller:

```
let viewControllerVisible = self.rootViewController?.presentedViewController
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check out this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6131205/iphone-how-to-find-topmost-view-controller). The gist of it is that you start with the window's `.rootViewController`. In my own code (using a `UINavigationController` as the `.rootViewController`, I use this (in `AppDelegate`):

```
if let nvc = self.window?.rootViewController as? UINavigationController {
    if let mvc = nvc.topViewController as? MasterViewController {
        // ... do something
    } else if let dvc = nvc.topViewController as? DetailViewController {
        // ... do something
    }
}
```

Note that if you are using the default template for a Master-Detail application, you will need to consider the `SplitViewController` which interposes itself, but that should be reasonably obvious from the boilerplate code.

Answer (score -1):

Inorder to get a reference to the top most view controller in the hierarchy try the following code

```
UIViewController *topController = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController;

while (topController.presentedViewController)
{
    topController = topController.presentedViewController;
}

return topController;
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want the topmost view on window try with this you will get the view.

```
[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] subviews] lastObject];
```

Comment: this gives View, not ViewController.