# Calling Functions From AppDelegate in swift3

Tags: ios, swift, appdelegate, onesignal

I'm using `OneSignal` to process notifications in my app. This is initiated in `AppDelegate.swift` where there is a function that handles received apps:

```
let notificationReceivedBlock: OSHandleNotificationReceivedBlock = { notification in
    print("Received Notification: \(notification!.payload.body)")
}
```

I then have a `TabViewController` with 5 tabs and each tab's navigationItem has a `UINavigationBarButton` that sends you to a messages view. I want to change the badge number in that button whenever a notification comes in to show that the user is getting new messages. I have a function inside every viewController (each of the 5 tabs) that will update this.

The problem is that the `AppDelegate` needs to call this function `updateBadgeNumber` and I don't know how to do this. Plus, some of the tabs may not even have been initialised yet. Does anyone know how to call functions in ViewControllers from the `AppDelegate`?

Thank you.

EDIT:

Found a solution thanks to @paulvs below. He linked me to an answer where I found this: [Find Top View Controller in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26859650/7168769)

Comment: Don't call any method from there just post a notification and add an observer to your view controller

Comment: Thank you for the help! The problem with your suggestion was that OneSignal is initialised in the AppDelegate and you feed it its observer functions to initialise it, so I couldn't add observers to every class and then feed them in the AppDelegate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer depends on whether your `UITabBarController` is the root view controller of your app.

1. If your `UITabBarController` is the root view controller, you likely have a reference to it in your app delegate and can use `UITabBarController`'s `selectedViewController` property to get the current view controller and then set the badge value. (If you don't have a reference, you can probably cast `window.rootViewController` to `UITabBarController` to access it.)
2. If it's not, you can use code [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12684721/1305067) to find the currently visible view controller. (Then to access the `UITabBarController`, you can probably cast `parentViewController` to a `UITabBarController`, and from there access the other view controllers and set their badge values, too.)

Comment: Thank you so much! I used the Swift code from another answer in that link you gave me! So I basically get the top ViewController and then do a switch to find out which class it is and then cast it to that class and call its respective updateBadge() function. I'll add the code I used to this question