# How to create view programmatically outside a view controller

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiprogressview

Currently I'm trying to create a UIProgressView that will be called with a manager class:

```
 func addProgressBar() {

        let rect = CGRect(x: 10, y: 70, width: 250, height: 0)
        let progressView = UIProgressView(frame: rect)
        progressView.progress = 0.0
        progressView.tintColor = UIColor.blue
        self.view.addSubview(progressView)
    }
```

This issue that's arising is the line:

```
 self.view.addSubview(progressView)
```

because the function isn't in a viewController I get the error:

> Value of type 'NetworkHelper' has no member 'view'

any idea how to add the progressView outside of a viewcontroller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you probably guessed it yourself, you need a `view` to which you would put the `progressBar`. I think the caller of the `addProgressBar` method should know the best where it would fit the best, so I would recommend using `progressBar` with an argument of a `UIViewController` type, which would be the target which is responsible for making a network call and thus is a target to put the progress bar into:

```
func addProgressBar(targetViewController: UIViewController) {
    // moreover, are you sure here that the height of the progressBar should be 0?
    let rect = CGRect(x: 10, y: 70, width: 250, height: 0)
    let progressView = UIProgressView(frame: rect)
    progressView.progress = 0.0
    progressView.tintColor = UIColor.blue
    targetViewController.view.addSubview(progressView)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you have to have a view to place it in. Either you grab the top viewcontroller and place it on that or you call your NetworkHelper class and pass it a view that it should place the progress bar in.

I use this method to grab the top viewcontroller

```
func topViewController() -> UIViewController? {
    guard var topVC = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController else { return nil }
    while let presentedViewController = topVC.presentedViewController {
        topVC = presentedViewController
    }

    return topVC
}
```

Comment: When I try and add the subview:  let topView = Utility.getTopViewController
        topView.addSubview(progressView), there is an error "Value of type '(Utility) -> () -> UIViewController?' has no member 'addSubview'"

Comment: That's because you're adding it to the viewcontroller. topView.view.addSubview(progressView) is what you want. :)

Answer (score 0):

You could get the topmost view controller, and add the subview to its view property.

[iPhone -- How to find topmost view controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6131205/iphone-how-to-find-topmost-view-controller)

Answer (score 0):

You can use "callbacks", either using Delegation design pattern

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Delegation.html

Or Swift's closures (Objective-C blocks)

You can return a "closure" from the function, this closure creates the progress. To be used on the view/viewController

```
 func addProgressBar() -> (UIView) -> () {

    return { view in
        let rect = CGRect(x: 10, y: 70, width: 250, height: 0)
        let progressView = UIProgressView(frame: rect)
        progressView.progress = 0.0
        progressView.tintColor = UIColor.blue
        view.addSubview(progressView)
    }
}
```

Then use this return value, in the view controller for example:

```
      (networkHelper.addProgressBar())(self.view)
```

---

---

---

The is if you want to make the progress view on the view controller, and manage it there.

```
class NetworkHelper {

    ...

    func doAnythingWithNetwork(withProgress: @escaping (NSProgress) -> (),
                               completion: @escaping (Data?, Error?) -> ()) {
        ...
        // When you get any progress (like in Alamofire for example).
        // Pass it to the callback
        withProgress(progress)
        ...
    }

}
```

Then in your viewController:

```
let networker = NetworkHelper()

...

@IBAction func buttonClicked(_ sender: Any?) {
    networker.doAnythingWithNetwork(withProgress: { [weak self] progress in
        // You can use your viewController here (note: use 'self?', not
        //     'self', here self is "weak", only to avoid memory leaks).
        // Note: Any update of the view must be in DispatchQueue.main
    }, completion: { [weak self] data, error in
        // Your usual completion handler.
    })
}
```

---

But the recommended solution is to make your `NetworkHelper` just a model, just to handle web requests and data. SOLID principles has a "Single Responsibility Principle", i.e. Design each object to have only one single responsibility.

The view (or viewcontroller) should handle the `addProgressBar`, and the NetworkHelper should pass this progress via a delegate or closure/block to the viewcontroller where the view is updated.