# Identify the page when app moves to background or foreground in IOS

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios

I want to identify the page user is on when the app moves to background.

Reason : When the app enters foreground, I need to log it as a page view in telemetry. So, it is important for me to understand which page the user was on when app moved to background.

Comment: Use your AppDelegate, there is a callback for this in it.     But, try to [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the app moves to background, it will trigger `OnResignActivation` and `DidEnterBackground` method, what you should do is that find the top viewcontroller in `DidEnterBackground` in `AppDelegate`.

```
String pageName;
public override void DidEnterBackground(UIApplication application)
{
    UIViewController controller = UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.RootViewController;
    while (controller.PresentedViewController != null)
    {
        controller = controller.PresentedViewController;
    }

    UIViewController c = findTopViewController(controller);
    pageName = c.Class.Name;
}

public UIViewController findTopViewController(UIViewController controller)
{
    if (controller is UINavigationController) {
        controller = (controller as UINavigationController).TopViewController;
        findTopViewController(controller);
    }
    else if (controller is UITabBarController)
    {
        controller = (controller as UITabBarController).SelectedViewController;
        findTopViewController(controller);
    }
    return controller;
}
```

Refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12684721/8187800) and comments under it.