# How to get UIAlertController over UIView in Objective C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertcontroller, addsubview, subviews

I am new to iOS Programming,
I have Implemented UITableViewController and getting that tableViewController design on my homepage like a popup, 
Backside I added Blur effect between homepage and tableViewController.
Both blur effect view and UITableView are added as subviews in main screen.

**Here is my problem:**

When I'm  validating UITextfields of tableViewController, alertController is appearing  backside of blur effect and tableViewController, I need that over tableViewController.

**How can I get??**

I used below Code for blur effect and tableView:

```
UIVisualEffect *blurEffect;
blurEffect = [UIBlurEffect effectWithStyle:UIBlurEffectStyleDark];
visualEffectView = [[UIVisualEffectView alloc] initWithEffect:blurEffect];        
visualEffectView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
[[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow addSubview:visualEffectView];

UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
viewaccept = (AcceptViewController *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"AcceptViewController"];
[viewaccept willMoveToParentViewController:self];

CGRect screen = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
CGRect newFrame = CGRectMake(0,screen.size.height/4, self.view.frame.size.width, 350);
UIEdgeInsets insets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0,10,0,10);

viewaccept.view.frame = UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(newFrame,insets);
CGRect splitframe = viewaccept.view.frame;
[viewaccept.view setFrame:splitframe];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow addSubview:viewaccept.view];
[self addChildViewController:viewaccept];
[viewaccept didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

I used below code to show alert:

```
 NSString *message = @"Email Id is already registered";
 UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:nil message:message preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
 [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];

 int duration = 3; // duration in seconds
 dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, duration * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
     [alert dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
 });
```

Comment: What have you tried? Share your code

Comment: try this one : [self.view bringSubviewToFront:yourAlertController.view];

Comment: I have updated my code..

Comment: Present `UIAlertController` on current presented `UIViewController` that is `viewaccept`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
UIWindow* topWindow = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
topWindow.rootViewController = [UIViewController new];
topWindow.windowLevel = UIWindowLevelAlert + 1;

UIAlertController* alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Title" message:@"Your Message" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

[alert addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"OK",@"confirm") style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel handler:^(UIAlertAction * _Nonnull action) {
  // continue your work

// important to hide the window after work completed.
// this also keeps a reference to the window until the action is invoked.
topWindow.hidden = YES;
}]];

[topWindow makeKeyAndVisible];
[topWindow.rootViewController presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: Hello Das,One more doubt I have implemented Touchid for fingerprint, that alert also have a same issues ,how would I get over my view.

Comment: @Shubam Gupta. Can you please give some more description about your issue regarding AlertController with touchid.

Answer (score 0):

you can present your alertController on child controller like:

```
[viewaccept presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: I have tried but still I am getting alert, on backside of uitabeviewcontroller

Comment: if you are adding your tableViewController as a child controller than present alertViewController on child controller instead of parent.

I mean instead of :   [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];

use:       [viewaccept presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];

Comment: @ShubamGupta - get the top VC and present your alert

Comment: viewaccept code in homepage.m and alertviewcontroller is appearing is smoother file like acceptviewcontroller.m

Comment: Than you can get the topViewController from the navigation stack or window and present your alert on this

Comment: @ShubamGupta [Use this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6131205/iphone-how-to-find-topmost-view-controller) to get topViewController & show the UIAlertController on that topViewController.