# MMDrawerViewController objective-c push to navigation view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, mmdrawercontroller

i am beginner iOS dev, I have my app with many controllers.
After login on LoginViewController (LoginViewController has segue relation with NavigationViewController) I do init MMDrawerViewController with this code:

```
-(void)initSidebarController{
    AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];

    UIViewController *leftView = [mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LeftViewController"];
    UIViewController *centerView = [mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"CenterViewController"];


    UINavigationController *leftNav= [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:leftView];
    UINavigationController *centerNav= [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:centerView];

    appDelegate.drawerController= [[MMDrawerController alloc]initWithCenterViewController:centerNav leftDrawerViewController:leftNav];

    appDelegate.drawerController.openDrawerGestureModeMask = MMOpenDrawerGestureModePanningCenterView;
    appDelegate.drawerController.closeDrawerGestureModeMask = MMOpenDrawerGestureModePanningCenterView;

    appDelegate.window.rootViewController = appDelegate.drawerController;
    [appDelegate.window makeKeyAndVisible];
}
```

Now I want to push **DishesViewController** on NavigationViewController when user **didSelectRowAtIndexPath** .
How can I do this correctly ?

[image]

[image]
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Go to the storyboard, select dishesViewController and select the identity inspector from the left pane and in the StoryboardID enter "dishesVC" then use this code :

```
CateringDishesViewController *vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"dishesVC"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController: animated:YES]
```

Comment: No visible @interface for 'UINavigationController' declares the selector 'pushViewController::'

Answer (score 0):

Please follow below step, I am sure it will work for you.

1) Get top `ViewController` ([Reference link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6131205/iphone-how-to-find-topmost-view-controller)).

2) If your MMDrawerController library configure is proper then you will get `MMDrawerController` as a top view controller.

3) Then find center `UINavigationController`

4) By using center navigation controller you can to new view controller into stack.

If you don't able to do it then provide sample source code with us. So we can provide exact solution.

Comment: Your top ViewController should be MMDrawerController what does it mean? ViewController must be a child of MMDrawerController? 
ViewController : MMDrawerController like this?

Comment: No, I mean to say if your side menu configure proper then you will get MMDrawerController as a top view controller.

Comment: how I can do this?
Then find center UINavigationController

Comment: like MMDrawerController* drawer = (MMDrawerController*) [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController

Comment: Then UINavigationController* navigation = (UINavigationController*) drawer.centerNav