# how to open react native particular screen from native (swift) code?

Tags: swift, react-native

I hope you are doing well.

I had managed to open the native screen from react-native but now want to open the react-native particular screen from native.

any idea?

**Tried this**

```
let jsCodeLocation = RCTBundleURLProvider.sharedSettings().jsBundleURL(forBundleRoot: "index", fallbackResource: nil)
let rootView = RCTRootView(bundleURL:jsCodeLocation as URL?, moduleName: "myapp", initialProperties: nil, launchOptions:nil)

let rootViewController = UIViewController()

rootViewController.view = rootView
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(rootViewController, animated: true)
```

Comment: which `Navigation` do u use?

Comment: @gran33 Actually I am new in react. Just try this way to navigate if you have any idea please share it. Thanks

Comment: You should find the top most `UIViewController` (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6131205/how-to-find-topmost-view-controller-on-ios) then go to its navigation controller and push your new VC on top of it. But, it's bad practice. That's the basic idea. If you'll use `react-navigation` or `react-native-navigation` the above idea won't work.

Comment: Yes but I want to push in react-native screen.

Comment: So my suggestion above will work