# What is the Use of Returning the Same function itself in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, viewcontroller

Well I see some syntax in the following function which returns the topMostViewController. This function is defined in AppDelegate

```
func topViewController(controller: UIViewController? = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        if let navigationController = controller as? UINavigationController {

            //***A topViewController which is Returning itself
            //***This is where I got Confusion
            return topViewController(controller: navigationController.visibleViewController)

        } else if let tabController = controller as? UITabBarController {
            if let selected = tabController.selectedViewController {
                return topViewController(controller: selected)
            }
        } else if let presented = controller?.presentedViewController {
            return topViewController(controller: presented)
        }
        return controller
    }
```

And it's used as

```
if (self.topViewController() as? SomeViewController) != nil {
            if orientation.isPortrait {
                return .portrait
            } else {
                return .landscape
            }
        }
```

I understood that the code is trying to set orientation based on the currently visible View Controller but I don't understand what is the necessity of returning the same function itself in `topViewController`. Also I see some syntax like

```
extension UIApplication {
    /// The top most view controller
    static var topMostViewController: UIViewController? {
        return UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController?.visibleViewController
    }
}

extension UIViewController {
    /// The visible view controller from a given view controller
    var visibleViewController: UIViewController? {
        if let navigationController = self as? UINavigationController {

          // *** Here it's returning Same variable i.e visibleViewController
          // *** a function could call itself recursively. But how can a Variable calls itself recursively?

          return navigationController.topViewController?.visibleViewController
            } else if let tabBarController = self as? UITabBarController {
                return tabBarController.selectedViewController?.visibleViewController
            } else if let presentedViewController = presentedViewController {
                return presentedViewController.visibleViewController
            } else {
                return self
            }
        }
    }
```

**Edited**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is called **recursion**. There is a condition in the recursion that cause t end the cycle :

- Not in the `navigationController`, because it has another visible controller
- Not in the `tabBarController`, because it has another visible controller
- Not presenting another controller, because the presented one is visible

if one of these appears -> we go down one level and call this function again until none of these true.

Comment: Thank you so much now I understood. :-). Does here https://stackoverflow.com/a/38124819/8331006 too the recursion happens implicitly?

Comment: No that is not recursion. Recursion means a function calls itself. There is no call of *itself* there.

Comment: In the above link they have used something like 
`override var topmostViewController: UIViewController? {
        return visibleViewController?.topmostViewController
    }`  here the variable returns same variable...If this is not implicitly similar to recursive then what is actually happening over here?

Comment: visibleViewController refers to another object with another `topmostViewController` that has very similar implementation. Although that is very similar to recursion, that is not called *recursive **function***.

Answer (score 2):

It is a [recursive function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)). The `topViewController` function calls itself to find the top most controller which is visible. The function will exit when `controller?.presentedViewController` returns `nil` (Which means that the value held by controller is the top most visible controller). You can also achieve the same without a recursive function as mentioned here: [How to find topmost view controller on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6131205/how-to-find-topmost-view-controller-on-ios), but it looks much more cleaner than the looping implementation.

Comment: Thank you for your efforts...Now I understood