# How to present view controller from a class method of UIViewController

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I have a subclass of UIViewController. In order to present an alert in its instance method I would do

```
[self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
```

This time I need to present this alert in a **class level** method. There is no known class method for selector 'presentViewController:animated:completion:'

Is there any workaround?

Comment: Find some view controller that suits your purpose and present in that. For example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6131205/how-to-find-topmost-view-controller-on-ios

Comment: @Roope Thanks. This is a good idea to find topmost controller from a class level method.