# What is the best way to present a view controller on top of everything in iOS?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

I'm trying to present a view controller that will be kept displayed above everything, regardless of the currently presented view controller, so it will be kept as displayed even if the view controller behind it will get dismissed, or starts to present another view controller.

I know how to find the topmost view controller (for example [as suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12684721/13301740)) but in this case presenting over this view controller will make the new view controller depends on the hierarchy of the parent controller, which I try to avoid.

Comment: Possibly, make a new window?

Answer (score 1):

Present the view from the *rearmost* view, the window. But give it a high z index so that it shows up in front of everything else.